# Optimizing an Inner Join when one of the tables is small

Tags: sql

I have a really small table T1 and a really huge table T2. I intend to inner join and get columns from both tables.

What is the best way to do this?

Do a inner join?

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 
    ON T1.col == T2.col
```

or

Filter rows from T2 using a semi join and then do a Inner Join?

```
temp = SELECT * 
FROM T1 
RIGHT SEMIJOIN T2 
    ON T1.col == T2.col;

SELECT * 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN temp 
    on T1.col == temp.col
```

Comment: Provided T2.col has a suitable index your RDBMS will make the optimal choice with the simpler query.

Answer (score 1):

`SEMIJOIN` is not a standard SQL operator.

In general, you would just use an `INNER JOIN` and let the optimizer choose the best execution plan.  For best performance, you want to be sure that you have an index on `col` in the larger table.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the DB engine. However most modern DB engines will choose the optimal execution in the first case. In the latter you kinda force their hand.